# Is there any way to get out of stock products from amazon using Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I tried Product Advertising API for fulfilling my need, but cant find any way to get any solution of my requirement.

Comment: [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com) is owned by Amazon but is **not** related to the amazon.com web site, so [tag:amazon-web-services] is not the tag you are looking for, for this question.

Comment: Opps!! my mistake, it should amazon Product Advertising API rather than amazon web service.
thanks.